# Standard contents of /etc/environment file in linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I'm running Linux Mint 14 and accidentally replaced the contents of /etc/environment file. It was originally something like:

```
PATH=/usr/bin
```

but with some extra stuff. At the moment, most commands don't work in the terminal. If I do "ls", I get "command not found". Does anyone know the standard contents of this file is?

Comment: Off-topic; belongs on [su] or [ubuntu.se]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On ubuntu 12.04 it is:

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games"
```